# Add oncontextmenu when preloading an image

Tags: jquery

I was able to add the following on a image link, to prevent the user using the contextual menu:

```
<img oncontextmenu = "return false;" src="...">
```

I want to do the same thing using jQuery, with no success:

```
// preload the image
var img = new Image();
img.src = src;
img.oncontextmenu = 'return false;';
....
```

What is wrong with my jQuery code?

Comment: That's not jQuery code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not jQuery, that's vanilla JS. It's $(img).on("contextmenu", function() { return false; });

Comment: my mistake.. it's a js function called inside jquery.